# How to change the path where Git creates ssh file while "remote add origin ..."?

Tags: windows, git, internationalization

Good times!

Please, hint me this moment - I use the Windows account with cyrillic account-name. When I try to add my local git repository to github.com, I get the mistake **"Could not create directory c/Users/\204\206"** ... and I suspect due to my account is cyrillic. 
So - how to change this behavior? I want to use Git without changing or renaming account?

Comment: what exact command did you run?

Comment: I've the same problem on my notebook. PHPStorm creates *.bat files in Temp directory of the current user account. On another PC all is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't create any directories when you add a remote repository.  That is, if you type a command like this:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:you/yourproject.git
```

The only thing that happens is that git adds a couple of lines to the `.git/config` file.

Comment: May be, I wrong - but I see the mistake "Could not create directory c/Users/\204\206" just after git-command